# Connect US BLM WMS to Mapbox

Tags: mapbox, wms

I am trying to add the WMS for the PLSS (public land survey system) published by BLM.gov to a Mapbox map, to make the Township/Range/Section grid visible, and I can't get it to display on the map. I suspect there's an issue with syntax between the Mapbox JS request and what the BLM WMS expects as a query.

I've been working with the mapbox published example for adding a WMS, modded for the BLM site, code below:

```
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'MY_KEY';
    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10',
        zoom: 8,
        center: [-95, 38]
    });

    map.on('load', function() {
        map.addSource('wms-test-source', {
            'type': 'raster',
            'tiles': [
            'https://gis.blm.gov/arcgis/services/Cadastral/BLM_Natl_PLSS_CadNSDI/MapServer/WmsServer?bbox={bbox-epsg-3857}&format=image/png&service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetMap&srs=EPSG:3857&width=256&height=256&layers=1'
        ],
        'tileSize': 256
    });
    map.addLayer(
        {
            'id': 'wms-test-layer',
            'type': 'raster',
            'source': 'wms-test-source',
            'paint': {}
        },
    'aeroway-line'
    );
});
```

Does anyone see what I need to change to get this to overlay the PLSS grid, I'd be very greatful!

Comment: Have you loaded the appropriate mapbox js and css files in the html?

Comment: Thomas, yes. I've been utilizing the codepen.io and jsfiddle.net links that mapbox provides with their example (which loads a wms from img.nj.gov over a map); because it displays the example correctly, I believe it should also display my PLSS overlay correctly if I get the code right.

Comment: yeah the code seems to be working can you please show the output from console which you are getting

Comment: I'm not getting any error messages or other output, but the mapbox is only showing the basemap and is not rendering any of the PLSS grid (i've also zoomed way in and way out to see if it was related to that). Is it overlaying the grid for you?

Comment: yes it is. please go through these examples  , 
 https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/wms/ 
 https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/wms/

Comment: Thanks, Thomas. The first link (using the tilelayer function) worked for me. The second link was my starting point for this thread and the code above. Thank you!

Comment: ok. let me add that as the answer for this question. Please do upvote and accept it to close it. ok?

Comment: @ThomasMartin I had to let the wait period expire before I could accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Thomas Martin's comment below, I utilized the tileLayer function as described here: [docs.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/wms](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/wms) to accomplish my goal. Code as per below:

```
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoicGV0cm9hbmFseXRpY2EiLCJhIjoiY2s2dTlicXQzMDdqbDNnbzhsNGo4ZjY0MCJ9.u5nBRLm8b6RwZKKXGh-L4w';
var map = L.mapbox.map('map')
    .setView([37, -99], 8)
    .addLayer(L.mapbox.styleLayer('mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11'));

// Add each wms layer using L.tileLayer.wms
var Sections = L.tileLayer.wms('https://gis.blm.gov/arcgis/services/Cadastral/BLM_Natl_PLSS_CadNSDI/MapServer/WmsServer', {
    format: 'img/png',
    transparent: true,
    layers: 2
}).addTo(map);

var Townships = L.tileLayer.wms('https://gis.blm.gov/arcgis/services/Cadastral/BLM_Natl_PLSS_CadNSDI/MapServer/WmsServer', {
    format: 'img/png',
    transparent: true,
    layers: 1
}).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 1):

PFA,

```
<script>
 L.mapbox.accessToken = '<your access token here>';
 var map = L.mapbox.map('map')
 .setView([37, -99], 3)
 .addLayer(L.mapbox.styleLayer('mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11'))

 var temperature = 
  L.tileLayer.wms('http://gis.srh.noaa.gov/arcgis/services/NDFDTemps/MapServer/WMSServer', {
  format: 'img/png',
  transparent: true,
  layers: 16
  }).addTo(map);

var precipitation = L.tileLayer.wms('http://nowcoast.noaa.gov/arcgis/services/nowcoast/analysis_meteohydro_sfc_qpe_time/MapServer/WmsServer', {
 format: 'image/png',
 transparent: true,
 layers: '5'
 }).addTo(map);

document.getElementById('temperature').onclick = function () {
var enable = this.className !== 'active';
temperature.setOpacity(enable ? 1 : 0);
this.className = enable ? 'active' : '';
return false;
};

document.getElementById('precipitation').onclick = function () {
var enable = this.className !== 'active';
precipitation.setOpacity(enable ? 1 : 0);
this.className = enable ? 'active' : '';
return false;
};
</script>
```

Refer this link for more info. https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/wms/